# phpExcel - putting an apostrophe before numbers

Tags: php, phpexcel

creating a cell with apostrophe before the number, example will be 20110101 then setCellValue to '20110101 (must be in Cell 'TEXT_FORMAT' already) the apostrophe must be hidden once the excel was generated. like in ms excel, when you put apostrophe before the number... it makes the cell into TEXT FORMAT and hide the apostrophe.

Answer (score 3):

You use `setCellValueExplicit()` rather than `setCellValue()`, because it allows you to specify the datatype for the value (and it defaults to a string, which is what you need).

If you really want to enforce the apostrophe as well, then you can apply the quotePrefix style setting for the cell (although this shouldn't really be necessary)

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A10')->setQuotePrefix(true);
```

although quotePrefix isn't supported by all Writers